# Extending Nagura's Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

Is it true that given any fixed $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $k > 0$ such that for all integers $n \geq k$, it follows that there exists a prime $p$ between $n$ and $(1 + \epsilon)n$?

If it is true, who discovered this result and where might I obtain a proof of it?

If it is not true, what would be one of the best extensions of Nagura's Theorem that is currently known?

Comment: FYI, this result also comes from the Prime number theorem, such as described in Wikipedia's [Prime gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds) article's "Upper bounds" section.